# Alias in SAS/SQL is not working

Tags: sql, sas

This SAS/SQL query returns a table DS_Dbtr_Status with column names FACS_Schema_ID and DBACCT and not the aliases as given.

```
proc sql outobs=10; **DS_Dbtr_Status**;
create table DS_Dbtr_Status as
    select
        FACS_Schema_ID as ID,
        DBACCT as ACCOUNT_NUM, 
         ...
    from sqlsrv10.acct_dbtr_status
    where Disposition ^= '9999';
quit;
```

Comment: what type of database are you connecting to and which ACCESS engine?  I can use ODBC to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server 2014 and the alias seem to work fine.

Comment: Are you sure you are not looking at the LABEL instead of the NAME of the column?

Comment: DomPazz: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and OLEDB

Comment: Tom: Maybe it is the LABEL.  I am quite new to SAS, so how do I change the label to reflect the alias as well?  Update: I just checked, the names are changes, but the labels are not.  Is there a command to set the labels equal to the names?

Comment: `label=' '` should do that (if the label is missing then it shows the name).  So  `FACS_Schema_ID as ID label=' '` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SAS you can specify the label directly as a column modifier in the SELECT clause just by quoting it.  The `label=` part of the modifier is optional:

```
    select
    FACS_Schema_ID as ID 'ID',
    DBACCT as ACCOUNT_NUM 'Account Number'
```

Using empty quotes will remove the labels:

```
    select
    FACS_Schema_ID as ID '',
    DBACCT as ACCOUNT_NUM ''
```

This doesn't affect the column name (which is determined by the alias), but does affect how the column appears in some procedures and in the table viewer.

Comment: Great answer.  I would suggest the `label=` while optional is a good idea (as it otherwise can be somewhat unclear what the label is doing) but that's a matter of style of course.